# Get all selected item from Spinner in recyclerview Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

I have used **Spinner** in **Recyclerview**.I have one button in Mainactivity. when i click that button, i need get all selected item from each row of recyclerview.**getSelectedItem()** method  will return the selected item from spinner but i think only for single item it is working.
I think no need to use **setOnItemSelectedListener**.

**My code is :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


RecyclerView recycler_view;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recycler_view=findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler_view.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    setAdapter();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}





private void setAdapter( ) {

        recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        StudentsListAdapter studentsListAdapter = new StudentsListAdapter(this);
        recycler_view.setAdapter(studentsListAdapter);
        // runLayoutAnimation(recycler_view, mSelectedItem);


}
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class StudentsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentsListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


String[] list={"Microbiology","Pharmacology","Microbiology","Forensic Medicine"};

String[] studentsName={"Student1","Student2","Studen3","Student4"};

Context ctx;

private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {



    @BindView(R.id.text_name)
    TextView text_name;


    @BindView(R.id.spinner1)
    Spinner spinner1;

    MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}

public StudentsListAdapter(Context ctx ) {
    this.ctx = ctx;

}

@NonNull
@Override
     public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.student_list_item, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {

    holder.text_name.setText(studentsName[position]);


    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, R.layout.spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    holder.spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    Log.d("Holder ",""+ holder.spinner1.getSelectedItem());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return studentsName.length;
}

 }
```

Comment: Use setOnItemSelectedListener and store selected values to another list. so you can access it in the activity.

Comment: Yes, i think that's only option we have.i have used Map for student and subject.it is working Thanks for  reply.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add an checkbox to know which of the items are selected.

```
Arraylist selectedStudent = new Arraylist();

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {

        holder.text_name.setText(studentsName[position]);


        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, R.layout.spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            Log.d("Holder ",""+ holder.spinner1.getSelectedItem());

        //checkbox listener
        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (isChecked){
            selectedStudent.add(studentsName[position]);
        }
    }

});
        }
```

In your activity, you can access your variable selectedStudent

```
 StudentsListAdapter studentListAdapter;

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              for (int i = 0; i < studentListAdapter.selectedStudent.size()-1 ; i++) {
              Log.d("studentSelected".""+studentListAdapter.selectedStudent.get(i));
        }
            }
        });
```

Comment: No. i cannot use checkBox .that's not requirement.Thanks for reply anyway

Comment: Well then you can just add a listener of every object that you have in your list and  implement what i did when the checkbox is being selected.

Comment: thank you. if i helped you please mark my answer by clicking the check icon. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use another List with the size of the Spinner list and add the default values of each spinner to the list. Whenever you change the value in the spinner change the value in the selected values list also.

now add a new method in the adapter to get the selected values list. and call that method on the button click